# Updating Azure AD passwords with application permission

Tags: http, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to change other users' passwords using Windows Graph API with application permissions, but always get a 403 error - insufficient permissions.

If delegated permissions are used, the Directory.AccessAsUser.All does the job. However, there is no such permission in application permissions.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/somebody@sandboxnice.onmicrosoft.com
Authorization: Bearer [token]
Content-type: application/json

{
"passwordProfile": {
"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
"password": "password00++"
}
}
```

The status code is 403, should be 204.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, we cannot use application permissions to update the Azure AD user's password. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#directory-permissions).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, I was just not sure if there was any way to do that anyway. What I did to solve that was to delete the user and create the user again with a different password. The only problem is that the User Object ID doesn't remain the same, which could cause me some problems in the future.